# CSF *Port Scan* detected - shared hosting

Tags: csf

We modified a few options in ConfigServer Firewall configuraion. Ever since the CSF blocking a lot of IP address. Following print sreen:

http://oi60.tinypic.com/kdlnh3.jpg

What can I modify thereto CSF not blocking a lot of IPs ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on CSF Guide:

You can change `PS_LIMIT` and `PS_INTERVAL` based on your needs.

> Port Scan Tracking.
>
> This feature tracks port blocks logged by iptables
>   to syslog. If an IP address generates a port block that is logged more
>   than PS_LIMIT within PS_INTERVAL seconds, the IP address will be
>   blocked.
>
> This feature could, for example, be useful for blocking hackers
>   attempting to access the standard SSH port if you have moved it to a
>   port other than 22 and have removed 22 from the TCP_IN list so that
>   connection attempts to the old port are being logged
>
> This feature blocks all iptables blocks from the iptables logs,
>   including repeated attempts to one port or SYN flood blocks, etc
>
> Note: This feature will only track iptables blocks from the log file
>   set in IPTABLES_LOG below and if you have DROP_LOGGING enabled.
>   However, it will cause redundant blocking with DROP_IP_LOGGING enabled
>
> Warning: It's possible that an elaborate DDOS (i.e. from multiple
>   IP's) could very quickly fill the iptables rule chains and cause a DOS
>   in itself. The DENY_IP_LIMIT should help to mitigate such problems
>   with permanent blocks and the DENY_TEMP_IP_LIMIT with temporary blocks
>
> Set PS_INTERVAL to "0" to disable this feature. A value of between 60
>   and 300 would be sensible to enable this feature

Comment: Thank! For eg.: Noew PS_LIMIT = 10, PS_INTERVAL = 300. Will I modify a few bigger value ?

Comment: Your welcome. Yes, I think configuring CSF with those values should run OK.